# PHP foreach in foreach in foreach / for loop overwrite with last

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have a weird problem looping through a multidimensional list of arrays.

The logic is:

Each department has many services and each service has many users.

This is the loop.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($departments); $i++) {

    for ($j=0; $j < count($departments[$i]->services); $j++) {

        $service_id = $departments[$i]->services[$j]->id;

        for ($k=0; $k < count($departments[$i]->services[$j]->users); $k++) {
            $user = $departments[$i]->services[$j]->users[$k];

            $user->service_id = $departments[$i]->services[$j]->id;

        }

    }

}
```

The result is:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Coafor",
    "company_id": 1,
    "services": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Coafat par scurt",
            "department_id": 1,
            "users": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "first_name": "Andrei",
                    "last_name": "Varlan",
                    "service_id": 4
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "first_name": "Claudiu",
                    "last_name": "Angheluta",
                    "service_id": 4
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the service id in each user needs to be the ID on main service but it`s overwritten by the last service id which is 4. I need the ID from the parent service so I can do further logic.

Any idea why is this happening or any idea how can I fix this bunch of code? Thank you.

## EDIT: as Mateusz requested to see all the departments array.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Coafor",
        "company_id": 1,
        "services": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Coafat par scurt",
                "department_id": 1,
                "users": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "first_name": "Andrei",
                        "last_name": "Varlan",
                        "service_id": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "first_name": "Claudiu",
                        "last_name": "Angheluta",
                        "service_id": 4
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Vopsit par mediu",
                "department_id": 1,
                "users": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "first_name": "Andrei",
                        "last_name": "Varlan",
                        "service_id": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "first_name": "Andrei",
                        "last_name": "Cazamir",
                        "service_id": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "first_name": "Luminita",
                        "last_name": "Cucu",
                        "service_id": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "first_name": "Claudiu",
                        "last_name": "Angheluta",
                        "service_id": 4
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Vopsit par lung",
                "department_id": 1,
                "users": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "first_name": "Andrei",
                        "last_name": "Varlan",
                        "service_id": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "first_name": "Andrei",
                        "last_name": "Cazamir",
                        "service_id": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "first_name": "Luminita",
                        "last_name": "Cucu",
                        "service_id": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "first_name": "Claudiu",
                        "last_name": "Angheluta",
                        "service_id": 4
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Frizerie",
        "company_id": 2,
        "services": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Tuns par mediu",
                "department_id": 2,
                "users": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "first_name": "Andrei",
                        "last_name": "Varlan",
                        "service_id": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "first_name": "Andrei",
                        "last_name": "Cazamir",
                        "service_id": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "first_name": "Luminita",
                        "last_name": "Cucu",
                        "service_id": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "first_name": "Claudiu",
                        "last_name": "Angheluta",
                        "service_id": 4
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Tuns par lung",
                "department_id": 2,
                "users": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "first_name": "Andrei",
                        "last_name": "Varlan",
                        "service_id": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "first_name": "Andrei",
                        "last_name": "Cazamir",
                        "service_id": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "first_name": "Luminita",
                        "last_name": "Cucu",
                        "service_id": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "first_name": "Claudiu",
                        "last_name": "Angheluta",
                        "service_id": 4
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Tuns si Vopsit par scurt",
                "department_id": 2,
                "users": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "first_name": "Andrei",
                        "last_name": "Varlan",
                        "service_id": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "first_name": "Andrei",
                        "last_name": "Cazamir",
                        "service_id": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "first_name": "Luminita",
                        "last_name": "Cucu",
                        "service_id": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "first_name": "Claudiu",
                        "last_name": "Angheluta",
                        "service_id": 4
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you post departments array?

Comment: Ya can you post the input array, how it looks, would be helpful in writing and debugging for us

Comment: You'll find this is a lot more readable if you change these to actual `foreach` loops

Comment: Of course guys. I edited the post. I also tried with foreach loop, the same result.

Comment: How are you checking the results? Are you printing departments array? It should work as it is.

Comment: I know that it shoud work but it doesn't. I'm building an API using Lumen API and I`m checking the results in Postman. And yes I'm printing the departments array.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`$user->service_id = $departments[$i]->services[$j]->id;`

to

`$user->service_id = $service_id;`

Comment: Tried it. Also tried foreach loop. 4 hours just debugging this code and still the same result ....

Comment: @SebastianB.if you still have not got it, paste the JSON of $department in the question. I think the current one you have pasted in the errored one with the service id 4 right?

Comment: @raidence I'm using laravel framework and I figured out that it is a problem related to laravel eager loading relationships. Still don't know why, but I'm 100% sure that this is the reason

Answer (score 0):

try using [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) instead of `for()` it makes things less complicated

```
<?php
foreach ($departments as $department) {
    foreach ($department->services as $service) {
        foreach ($service->users as $user) {
            $user->service_id = $service->id;
        }
    }
}
```